# Launch In-App Guidance on demand from Aura/LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

**Is it possible to launch In-App guidance on-demand via Code?**

For example, check the following screenshot:
[image]

Highlighted "help" buttons need to launch the In-App Guidance prompt, configured via standard point-click features in Setup Area.

Currently, I get a URL like the following, from In-App Guidance builder, but it's of no use:
https://saas-ruby-11262-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/app/MyCustomApp/n/MyTab?0.promptId=MyPromptName

Calling this URL via LWC or Aura is possible, but will refresh the whole page, and the user will lose the flow in progress and will start over again.

I am not sure if something like this is on the roadmap of In-AppGuidance (Could be an idea to post), or already exists (which I am missing).

Comment: Is your requirement to open the link specified in each of the `Help` button in a new page or tab? That way, In-App guidance defined for the resulting page shows up within the new page/ tab. And the user can get back to the current page for further steps? If yes and if you are using LWC, then `NavigationMixin` seems to support `window.open(url)` browser API. Would that help in your case?

Comment: Thanks @arut we are looking to do that only, only challenge is loading the whole app again from scratch in the new window :(

Comment: Didn't understand the functional significance of this statement `only challenge is loading the whole app again from scratch in the new window`? Why would you need app to load on the new window again? Could you elaborate with some use case?